# rails admin_data showing development db instead of production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, administration

ive successfully deployed admin_data onto heroku.

i can visit

myapp.herokuapp.com/admin_data

and the admin_data page shows. however it shows my development db. what's worse is that it actually shows my old entries (no longer exist).

is it possible for admin_data to show the production db?

i have an admin.rb file with the following...

```
AdminData.config do |config|
    config.is_allowed_to_view = lambda {|controller| return true if (Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.production?) }
end
```

am i missing something?

ive looked at the https://github.com/bigbinary/admin_data/wiki but cannot seem to find anything about making the production db show up

thank you!

UPDATE:

sorry i must be mistaken but... isn't visiting myapp.herokuapp.com my production site? and if i create a user there, isn't it being stored on herokus pg database? i was trying to view that database, and i thought going to myapp.herokuapp.com/admin_data would display that while going to localhost:3000/admin_data would show the users from the db on my local machine.

how do i view the database thats storing the user created from heroku with admin_data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Heroku application only has one database attached to it. If you're viewing the pages via a Heroku URL then you are viewing whatever database that application is using. You don't have multiple development/staging/production databases.

Comment: wait doesn't heroku use their own postgres db? for example, if i create a new user through heroku, it doesn't show up on my User table on my local machine

Comment: Correct - creating a user on heroku won't create it in your local user table but your original post says you visit myapp.herokuapp.com. What are you expecting to occur?

Comment: sorry i must be mistaken but... isn't visiting myapp.herokuapp.com my production site? and if i create a user there, isn't it being stored on herokus pg database? i was trying to view that database, and i thought going to myapp.herokuapp.com/admin_data would display that while going to localhost:3000/admin_data would show the users from the db on my local machine